# Cheap solution to unscrew and screw back a refillable lighter valve (to clean a lighter)

Tags: screws, gas, valve, screwdriver

Here is the valve that need to be unscrewed:
[image: Here is the valve that need to be unscrew]

the lighter:

[image: the lighter]

I have seen some [expensive solution](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_sacat=0&_nkw=lighter%20Filler%20Inlet%20Tool&_sop=15), and I'm not even sure they would fit since those valve and removal tool might not be standard.

I have tried with 2 small slotted screwdrivers, but without success.

Any idea?

(A low quality gas that contain impurity blocked the valve)

Comment: Not sure I see how this fits in with do-it-yourself home improvement?

Comment: Despite the name, diy is specifically a home repair/improvement discussion area. unless you are living in that lighter, this is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Go to basement, garage sale, or thrift store and pick up an old, regular screwdriver about the right size to fit the slot in the lighter.
Use a file, hacksaw, angle grinder or mototool type device to cut a slot in the screwdriver. Make the slot big enough to fit around the gas nipple.
Unscrew as needed.